# Why does XMLHttpRequest() not see external variables?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This variable is defined inside `data`:

```
data () {
  return {
    isSent: false,
    (...)
```

When trying to call the method here:

```
methods: {
  sendEmail () {
    let isSent = this.isSent

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText)
        this.isSent = true
(...)
```

linter says there is an unused variable defined. When I remove the `let isSent...` initialization, linter says about undefined variable.

*I saw the Q&A related to JS closures, but information there, although useful and broad, is very general and doesn't solve more specific issues like this one.*

How should I get to the variable from inside the `xhr` function?

Comment: It seems to be in the same scope, so why do you refer to it by this.isSent instead of just isSent ?

Comment: Your suggestion to leave out `this` is correct. But the scope is a different one. `sendMail` has another scope than the anonymous func for onreadystatechange.

Comment: @mbuechmann there are different scopes but the inner one still points to the external one, which means the variables of the external scope are visible.

Comment: Updated my answer to be more clear with how it works, and changed the _closure sample_ to show it is not related to your last edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` isn't what you think it is. Change the function to a arrow function, it should preserve the context of `this` to be what you expect.

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText)
        this.isSent = true
...
```

For more information on arrow functions, see the [documention on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)